# Loading Scripts on Specific Pages

Tags: conditional-content, child-theme, page-specific-settings

In child theme I created a functions.php file that loads scripts and style files, the code is below.
The section that loads libraries and scripts to all pages other than admin, in other words the first two functions, works as expected.
However, the third function, which is designed to load a script for a specific page does not load.
It appears that my problem has to do with specifying the page condition. The rest of the code for register and enqueue works if it is placed in the general function that loads scripts for any page other than admin pages.
I've researched this can can't find any examples showing why the approach I've used is not working.
I've swapped the page id with the name of the page but to no avail.

Any suggestion on the source of the problem would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

```
    <?php

function scripts () {
    if ( !is_admin() ) { 
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jqueryUI', "path", array('jquery')); //register custom UI library
        wp_enqueue_script('jqueryUI');
        wp_register_script('popUp1', ("path"), array('jquery', 'jqueryUI'));
        wp_enqueue_script('popUp1');
        wp_register_script('popUpText', 'path', array('jquery', 'jqueryUI'));
        wp_enqueue_script('popUpText');
    }
}

add_action('init', 'scripts');

//INSERT CSS    files into the header
function styles () {
    if ( !is_admin() ) {
        wp_register_style('jqueryUIcss', "path");
        wp_enqueue_style('jqueryUIcss');
        wp_register_style('valuecss', "path");
        wp_enqueue_style('valuecss');
    }
}   
    add_action('init', 'styles');

//Add scripts for pop ups on "how to estimate value" page
function pagePopUps1 () {
    if ( is_page(16)) { 
        wp_register_script('popUpVideo1', "path", array('jquery', 'jqueryUI'));
        wp_enqueue_script('popUpVideo1');

    }
}

add_action('init', 'pagePopUps1');  



//End of file
?>
```

Note for the sake of brevity I removed the src's but these have been validated and are not the source of the problem.

Comment: You can [read this article](http://meathanjay.wordpress.com/2014/05/25/wordpress-enqueue-stylesscripts-into-specific-page/), hope it helps:

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest moving the script registering into the init action, and moving the enqueue(s) into a callback hooked onto `wp_print_scripts`.

Eg.

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_those_scriptsNstyles' );

function register_those_scriptsNstyles() {
    wp_register_script( .. your script params .. );
    wp_register_style( .. your style params ..  );

    ..etc..
}

add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'enqueue_those_scriptsNstyles' );

function enqueue_those_scriptsNstyles() {

    if( !is_page( 'some-page' ) ) // If it's not the given page, stop here
        return;

    wp_enqueue_script( .. your script params .. );
    wp_enqueue_style( .. your style params .. );

    ..etc..
}
```

**NOTE:** Despite the hook name, i'm pretty sure `wp_print_scripts` should also be fine for enqueuing styles to. The important factor is to just ensure the hook you use occurs late enough for the conditional template tags to be set, ie. `is_page`, `is_category` and so on..
If not, try `wp_head` instead.. eg. `add_action( 'wp_head', 'your-callback' )`

**EDIT:** For styles, just like the admin side, the public facing side has an action for styles to.. which is `wp_print_styles`..(hook enqueues for styles to there).

Hope that helps..

Comment: In some cases `wp_print_scripts` might be too late for enqueues (without playing with priorities), because it has some script localization stuff hooked to it. Codex strongly recommends running enqueues on `init` only. Also conditional tags are documented as available at `init`, it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Rarst would you mind linking to the specific page(s) or sources please so i can have a read of the information?

Comment: @t31os see [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) in Codex and `wp_just_in_time_script_localization()` that is hooked to `wp_print_scripts`. I am not sure it **will** break something, but Codex recommends `init` and I think it makes sense to stick with that for consistency.

Comment: I'm not convinced there's a valid argument to not hook onto `wp_print_scripts` when used correctly. Have you looked at what `wp_just_in_time_script_localization` actually does, it's a callback that localizes the autosave.js script? If concern is with hooking onto it to early, then the fix is simple.. `add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'enqueue_those_scriptsNstyles', 11 );`. This hook was designed for enqueues, it's the equivalent of `admin_print_scripts`, just for the public facing side of the site..

Comment: @t31os _This hook was designed for enqueues_ I am fuzzy on historical reasoning, but I disagree on functional. Printing and enqueueing are distinctly different actions that are often decoupled. I see no particular reason that enqueues should be hooked there, especially when documentation explicitly recommends to use other hook. Overall it's nothing major but as above - I believe sticking with `init` for this is best practice kind of thing.

Comment: @Rarst - Perhaps you would be so kind as to share with me what you think `wp_print_scripts` and `wp_print_styles` are supposedly meant for then?

Comment: @t31os New info - found "Use provided wp_print_scripts hook to
register/enqueue new scripts" in source so I concede on that... Yay for documentation mess, personally I am sticking with `init` because it's cleaner to have most of stuff there. :)

Comment: @Rarst - No worries mate... ;) The problem with using init is that you don't get access to conditional tags to selectively make the enqueue, which you will when using the `wp_print_scripts` and `wp_print_styles` hooks.

Comment: @t31os ehm... curiously conditional tags docs say they should work _on or after the init action_. I am having a blast with docs today. :((( PS for the record I use more roundabout way with scripts to load everything in footer, so rarely work with hooks "in the beginning".

Comment: Nacin introduced the init note on the conditional tags page with this revision: http://codex.wordpress.org/index.php?title=Conditional_Tags&oldid=96321 ..but i don't think that's technically correct. John P Bloch and TheDeadMedic summed up it well here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245063/problem-with-is-page-conditional-in-wordpress (init is too early).

Comment: Ok, found a better hook: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L676 .. Note the comments for the wrapper function(but i'd still say `wp_print_scripts` is also appropriate).

Comment: I feel i might be misuing the comments here, but this is the last comment now(hehe). Wrote some basic test code and blogged about it, see here: http://wp.me/pmqyR-3w

Answer (score 0):

The first things to check in such cases:

- is hooked function firing properly;
- is condition being evaluated to expected result.

Add `var_dump(  is_page(16) );` to your function and see if these are working as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. This confirmed that the returned result is false.

Comment: @dorich see our huge messy comment discussion on other answer, it seems that (on the contrary to documentation) `init` hook is too early for `is_page()` to work.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I did wonder why the "!is_admin" works with "init" when the page specific won't. I'm naive on the use of php, conditional tags and action hooks so this is a learning experience. Is this just a case of changing the "add action" to a different hook (say wp or wp_head) or is there more to it?

Comment: @dorich yep, move it to another hook, again - see other answer for details

Comment: Thanks.  I tried wp_head to no avail but using wp appears to be loading the script as needed.